# Create id and check if it exists in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

How generate a unique id and push it through an object to an array, on condition that this id property value does not already exist in any of the array objects?

As per React code excerpt below, function "saveColor" was supposed to do that, attaching current state background color, so that an object would look similarily to those in the palettes array:

```
state = {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    palettes: [
    {id: 2, color: "crimson"},
    {id: 1, color: "skyblue"},
    {id: 0, color: "rebeccapurple"},
    {id: 4, color: "magenta"}
    ]
}

    saveColor = () => {
    let previousPalettes = this.state.palettes;
    previousPalettes.push(this.state.backgroundColor);

    this.setState({
        palettes: previousPalettes
    })
    }
```

Comment: That is a bad duplicate reference. It presupposes a certain solution, but there are better solutions than looking up the id values in that array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you need `id` here, but if you really need it - look at this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid